# Hashtable with limited size?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, hashtable

For managing some cache, I need a sort of Hashtable with the ability to remove the oldest elements in order to keep the MAXSIZE last elements in the table. I need to program this in Java but any algorithm with pseudo code would be fine too.

```
public interface LimitedHashtable<K, V> {
    void put(K k, V v); // will remove the oldest element from the table if size > MAXSIZE
    V get(K k);
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know is to keep a queue of the keys in your hash, and use that to expel keys when the table & queue get too big

Comment: All answers are clean but I picked your method.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) with an overridden `removeEldestEntry` -- if it returns `size() > MAXSIZE`, you'll have what you want. One of `LinkedHashMap`'s constructors also has a boolean that says whether the "oldest" entry means the one that was added longest ago, or the one that was accessed longest ago.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using Guava's [`CacheBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html), which offers a [`maximumSize()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#maximumSize%28long%29) amongst other options. Note that this behavior is more nuanced than what you might be looking for:

> Specifies the maximum number of entries the cache may contain. Note
>   that the cache may evict an entry before this limit is exceeded. As
>   the cache size grows close to the maximum, the cache evicts entries
>   that are less likely to be used again. For example, the cache may
>   evict an entry because it hasn't been used recently or very often.

Answer (score 1):

You want a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). You'll have to add some hooks to remove entries when that map gets too big.